# Creating Interaction Studio Activity for ExactTarget Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to build a Custom Activity so it appears as a Custom Activity in Journey Builder. I've followed [these steps](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/custom-components/custom-activities.html#defining-a-custom-activity-using-app-center) which instructs me to **Click 'Create an a new Interaction Studio Activity'** in App Center, but I don't see this option anywhere in App Center. Am I looking in the wrong place?

[image: App Center Templates]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a MarketingCloud Application with type HubExchange.

You will have to define the entire application before you can obtain APIKeys and gain visibility for creating Custom Interaction Studio Activities/Triggers. If you don't see this functionality available after defining your app, you're most likely missing a role assignment.

Send an email to codeATexacttarget.com with your Code@ username and they'll get you setup.

Comment: Hello Benjamin, I sent an email to code but did not hear back. Is there a different email address I can use or should I open a 3Sixty case for this?

Comment: Has this been resolved Elliot?